# Weight loss after Bankart surgery

Tags: weight-loss, shoulders

I am 27 years old guy and having weight upto 95kg. For 2 months ago i had a bankart surgery of my right shoulder, in which 3 anchors were installed inside the shoulder. What types of exercises i can do for weight loss, without affecting my shoulder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a slap repair. It is the same surgery, only the anchor (I had only one) is placed at the anterior part of the labrum.

This kind of surgery has an incredibly long recovery time, because the cartilague takes a lot to heal. After some google you will see how professional pitchers are out of the game for nearly a year. And they are professional athletes with personal therapists at their disposal...

You have to follow instructions from your surgeon. But in the general case it goes like this: In the first four to six months after the surgery only stationary bike should be allowed. You want to avoid impact activities such as running, and you don't want to risk falling on that arm (which would definitely ruin the surgery).

After the six month my surgeon allowed me to start running.

At 8 months post surgery I started to swim. At 12 months I started strength training at the gym.

Now (17 months post op) I can do whatever I want, but I will stay away from heavy shoulder presses, forever.

Be patient. Only the stationary bike for the moment. And no, don't use an elliptical machine or anything similar (you may fall on that arm). Just the stationary bike.

Comment: Thank you Mephisto. But i more query, i.e. after 17 months are you able to do lift heavy dumbles for your bisceps or any other exercise except the shoulder ?

Comment: @JuyalJee I don't do biceps isolation but I do a lot of compound pull (row) and push. I feel I could grab heavy dumbbells and do biceps curls or whatever I wanted, shoulder presses too. The thing is, I read here and there that therapists recommend to avoid shoulder presses after having suffered a bankart or slap surgery, because it puts a lot of stress on the shoulder joint at unusual angles. Now this is the point: you don't have nerves in the cartilague, so it feels completely normal, but you don't know how strongly it has re-attached to the bone. Hence the need to give it ample time to heal.

Comment: I know how frustrating it can be, but be patient. Forget about anything else than stationary bike and physical therapy at the present moment. Patience pays here. At the six-months mark, forced to avoid anything stressful on my shoulders, I discovered that running can be rewarding too (I did the "Couch to 5K" program, thanks to some nice podcasts at www.nhs.uk). And at the 8 months mark, I discovered that swimming is also not bad. Be patient. The iron will have to wait, but eventually you will be back to the gym. Don't ruin it. A second surgery is much less likely to succeed.